# The xgboost for multi-class classification gives different classification errors for options 'multi:softmax' vs 'multi:softprob'

Tags: r, machine-learning

Used the option 
`param['objective'] = 'multi:softmax'` and calculated the error

Then used the option
`param['objective'] = 'multi:softprob'` and calculated the error

The classification error is significantly higher in the case of `'multi:softprob'`. Dataset and other inputs and options remain the same

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why do you expect that both should have the exact same classification error?

Answer (score 0):

The only change made is changing the option. This option was changed to get the probability of output. 
There is a work around for this. See the code below. However, need to train the model twice which is redundant.

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/multiclass_classification/train.py

Hope I could make this clear.